# Panda Iterate dataframe and compare date-time with another dataframe date-time and find nearest date time values (one smaller and one greater)

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, csv, date

I have 2 csv files -

CSV A-

```
Col1        Date/Time         Col3    
75      2023/01/02 15:37:53 52582.12
23      2023/01/02 15:38:11 52577.12
```

CSV B-

```
Col1   Col2       Date/Time             Col4       Col5       Col6
23      XY      2023/01/02 15:37:49  NO_ERROR  NO_ERROR      AA
25      AB      2023/01/02 15:37:51  NO_ERROR  NO_ERROR      BB
31      CF      2023/01/02 15:37:56  NO_ERROR  NO_ERROR      CC 
35      CV      2023/01/02 15:38:10     ERROR  NO_ERROR      DD
76      FH      2023/01/02 15:38:15  NO_ERROR  NO_ERROR      EE
79      FG      2023/01/02 15:38:21  NO_ERROR  NO_ERROR      FF
```

I want to iterate the CSV-A and compare the Date/Time with CSV-B 'Date/Time' column and find out the 2 closure 'Date/Time'
from CSV-B(one is smaller and one is greater), and append these 2 closure 'Date/Time' and few other column in the same row like below -

```
A_df = pd.read_csv('csv_A')
B_df = pd.read_csv('csv_B',usecols = ['Date/Time','Col2','Col4'])
for _, row in A_df.iterrows():
//compare date logic and append output into existing row OR create separate dataframe.
```

Final output I need is like below -

```
          Col1     Date/Time           Col3     CSV_B_Date_Smaller  CSV_B_Col2   CSV_B_Date_greater  CSV_B_Col2
Row 1 -   75    2023/01/02 15:37:53  52582.12   2023/01/02 15:37:51     AB      2023/01/02 15:37:56     CF
Row 1 -   23    2023/01/02 15:38:11  52577.12   2023/01/02 15:38:10     CV      2023/01/02 15:38:15     FH
```

Thank you for the help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a double [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), once with `direction='backward'`, the other with `direction='forward'`:

```
A_df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(A_df['Date/Time'])
B_df['Date/Time'] = pd.to_datetime(B_df['Date/Time'])

cols = ['Date/Time', 'Col2']

out = pd.merge_asof(
    pd.merge_asof(
        A_df,
        B_df[cols].rename(columns={'Date/Time': 'CSV_B_Date'}).add_suffix('_Smaller'),
        left_on='Date/Time',
        right_on='CSV_B_Date_Smaller',
        direction='backward',
    ),
    B_df[cols].rename(columns={'Date/Time': 'CSV_B_Date'}).add_suffix('_greater'),
    left_on='Date/Time',
    right_on='CSV_B_Date_greater',
    direction='forward',
)
```

*NB. I'm assuming here that the two dataframes are already sorted by date (this is required by `merge_asof`).*

Output:

```
   Col1           Date/Time      Col3  CSV_B_Date_Smaller Col2_Smaller  CSV_B_Date_greater Col2_greater
0    75 2023-01-02 15:37:53  52582.12 2023-01-02 15:37:51           AB 2023-01-02 15:37:56           CF
1    23 2023-01-02 15:38:11  52577.12 2023-01-02 15:38:10           CV 2023-01-02 15:38:15           FH
```